# how to combine two requests from foursquare?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foursquare

A newbie here working with FourSquare API. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but I need to pull in data from a search via "https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search". However, along with that I'd like to have more details about each venue such as their hours of operation and other details about the venue aside from the generic contact and name. What I've done is nested an ajax call-the search api and then within search venue, do another venue detail search.

```
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?limit=4&"+$this.settings.key+"&ll="+$this.currentLocation.coord+"&intent=checkin",
    data: inputData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res, req) {
      var data = res.response.venues;
      $('.results').find('.loading').addClass('hide');
      $.each(data, function(index, venue) {
        return $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/"+venue.id+"?"+$this.settings.key,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(res, req) {
            data[index].details = detail = res.response.venue;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  })
).then(function(data) {
  var results = data.response.venues;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your "return" will return only the first loop of your $.each. And I am not sure you can return $.ajax like this. You should return data variable after your 2nd Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

```
var request1 = $.get(...);
var request2 = $.get(...);

$.when(request1 , request2 ).done(function() {
    // when both are completed
});
```

Comment: Hi @murali, the second request depends on the first request for the resulted array. I can't seem to produce what I need from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) Javascript library. Pass an array of venue IDs as the first argument into `async.each` and that should get you started. `async.waterfall` can also help you handle the case where you need to pass data from one asynchronous function to the next.